# Custom passport strategy with global AuthGuard

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, nestjs

I've implemented JWT authentication as described in that page https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication

When I use `@UseGuard` decorators for specific controllers it works fine. However if I set this in `main.ts` using `useGlobalGuards` then my strategy is not used and probably the default one is used.

```
app.useGlobalGuards(new (AuthGuard('jwt')));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your app.module and the AuthGuard ?

Comment: `new (AuthGuard('jwt'))` should be `new AuthGuard('jwt')`. But I agree with Yesub, it would be great if you could show more code.

Comment: shouldn't it be `app.useGlobalGuards(new (AuthGuard('jwt')()));` new should need constructor braces?!